# How to train/test split low frequency data so that both sets have at least one entry?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have a dataframe `df4` which contains film information (`Budget {scaled}, Year, Runtime, IMDB, Director(s)`) and a personal rating (integer between 0 and 10 inclusive). I'm trying to teach myself data science (and python) and use it for various models. Right now I'm trying to build a Linear Regression model.

To include the Director information I used one-hot encoding, after excluding all entries where the Director only had one film in the dataframe. Then I use train_test_split to create those dataframes:

```
df4[['Budget']] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df4[['Budget']])

aa  =df4['Director(s)'].value_counts()
bb = aa[aa>1]
cc = list(bb.index.values)
df4 = df4[df4['Director(s)'].isin(cc)]

df4dummies = pandas.get_dummies(df4[['Director(s)']])

X = pandas.concat([df4[['Budget', 'Year', 'Runtime', 'IMDB']], df4dummies], axis=1)
y = df4['Rating']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=16)

ohligr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
ohligr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = ohligr.predict(X_test)
```

While the model runs some of the predicted ratings are enormous and negative.

I looked over each entry and realised that the erroneous predicted values corresponded to films which shared a director, who only had films allocated to the test dataframe. There were 8 directors like this out of 160. I failed to find a solution in the function documentation to prevent this.

My first idea for a solution was to loop through `X_test['Directors']`, check each entry for a counterpart in `X_train` and move the entry over if one isn't found and move the same entry for `y_train/y_test`. That method would randomise the size of the split though depending on how the directors were allocated.

Thanks :)